# Is it possible to hide the ul background image over each li element?

Tags: html, css

In order to make a timeline as below, I have created an `ul` element with background image and give each `li` element a background color.

[image]

**The source code as below:**

```
<style>
body{
    //background: url(http://ut-images.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/The-Brightest-of-Stars.jpg)
}
ul {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/AmIstws.gif");
    background-position: 0 14px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
li {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  float: left;
}
span {
    background-color: white;
}
</style>


<ul>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
</ul>
```

However, if I set the `body` without a `solid background color`, the `ul` background image will breakthrough the `li` element as below.

[image]

**The source code as below:**

```
<style>
body{
    background: url(http://ut-images.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/The-Brightest-of-Stars.jpg)
}
ul {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/AmIstws.gif");
    background-position: 0 14px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
li {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  float: left;
}
span {
    background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

I want to ask is it possible to make something like below?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: hey are you open for change in html as well ??

Comment: That background makes the text extremely hard to read. I'd use a brighter color, maybe white and then add a little drop shadow to make sure it is readable when it overlaps the brighter parts of the background. If you do that make sure to specify a background color too so that it is still readable if the images are slow to/fail to load. Also, `//` doesn't make things a comment in CSS, it only supports `/* */` style comments.

Comment: then check my answer which i post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if you are open for change in html structure :

http://jsfiddle.net/MBNZ8/

changes in li : `<li><span></span><div>20130307</div><span></span></li>`

```
body{
    background: url(http://ut-images.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/The-Brightest-of-Stars.jpg)
}
ul {


    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
li {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  float: left;



}
span {
   background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/AmIstws.gif");
    background-position: 0 13px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 31px;
}
div {
    float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your original question: No it cant be done. What I would do is rearrange the html slighty:

```
<ul>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
<li><span></span>20130307</li>
</ul>
```

The take the background image off the UL and apply it to the span, something like this

```
span {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/AmIstws.gif");
    display: inline-block;
    height:10px;
    width:80px;
    margin:0 3px;
}
```

You'd have to mess around with the margins etc to get it perfect

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm this seems quite difficult. 
I would say it's impossible but we can certainly try to achieve a sort of *illusion*.
My first thoughts would be to get rid of the `<hr>` and toy around with :after and :before pseudo-elements.

I would add a straight line after each li

```
li:after{
   background: white;
   content: "";
   width: 30px;
   height: 2px;
   top: 13px;
   right: -16px;
   position: absolute;
}
```

and one before the first one.

```
 li:first-child:before{
    background: white;
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    top: 13px;
    left: -16px;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/8SKXy/1/

Still sort of a hack, but it works ok. No extra markup (you can even remove all the span tags), and semantic is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with `background: transparent`. If something is transparent, all the levels below it are visible including the background line on the `<ul>`.

You can achieve that effect, without changes to your HTML, if you are okay with using a `fixed` background. You simply specify the same background for the `body` and `span`, each with a [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-attachment) of `fixed`. Using `fixed` will cause the two backgrounds to be aligned and look like part of the same background.

```
<style>
body{
    background-image: url("The-Brightest-of-Stars.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #001;
}
ul {
    background-image: url("AmIstws.gif");
    background-position: 0 14px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
li {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none outside none;
  float: left;
}
span {
    background-image: url("The-Brightest-of-Stars.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    background-color: #001;
}
</style>
```

As I commented on the question, you might want to change the text a little to improve the readability. The above CSS includes a text `color`, `text-shadow` and a `background-color`
for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: 
make another element and set that background as this element background, insert it between the spans and around.

Its a simple trick and worked, just need some adjustments on css.

css: `ul li small { background: #CC0000; width: 100px; height: 20px; float: left; }
ul li:first-child  { width: 200px; }
ul li:first-child small { background: #CC0000; width: 200px; }
ul li:last-child small { width: 200px; }
ul li:last-child small { background: #CC0000; width: 200px; }`

html: `<ul>
    <li><small></small></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><small></small></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><small></small></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><small></small></li>
    <li><span>20130307</span></li>
    <li><small></small></li>
</ul>`

check out the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt5nD/)